# Проверить была ли произведена запись в структуру

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define NOT_VALID_MATRIX 1
    #define OK 0
    typedef struct matrix_struct {
        double** matrix;
        int rows;
        int columns;
    } matrix_t;

    int validMatrix(matrix_t *matrix) {
        int returnValue = 0;
        if ((*matrix).columns > 0 && (*matrix).rows > 0) {
            returnValue = 1;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }


    int create_matrix(int rows, int columns, matrix_t *result) {
        int returnValue = OK;
        if (rows > 0 && columns > 0) {
            (*result).rows = rows;
            (*result).columns = columns;
            (*result).matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(double*));
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                (*result).matrix[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(double));
            }
        } else {
            returnValue = NOT_VALID_MATRIX;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    int main() {
      matrix_t matrix;
      matrix_t matrix2;

      create_matrix(2, 2, &matrix);
      create_matrix(3, 0, &matrix2);

      int result = validMatrix(&matrix);
      printf("%d ", result);
      result = validMatrix(&matrix2);
      printf("%d ", result);
      return 0;
    }
```

Как проверить, была ли выделена память/произведена запись под структуру? Что ни поставлю в условие validMatrix, это условие всегда выполняется.
Поставил `(*matrix).matrix != NULL`, вроде как сработало. Но сработало только в мейне, в тестах с библиотекой <check.h> все равно проходит условие.
Вот код с тестом:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <check.h>
    #define NOT_VALID_MATRIX 1
    #define OK 0
    typedef struct matrix_struct {
        double** matrix;
        int rows;
        int columns;
    } matrix_t;

    int validMatrix(matrix_t *matrix) {
        int returnValue = 0;
        if ((*matrix).matrix != NULL) {
            returnValue = 1;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }


    int create_matrix(int rows, int columns, matrix_t *result) {
        int returnValue = OK;
        if (rows > 0 && columns > 0) {
            (*result).rows = rows;
            (*result).columns = columns;
            (*result).matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(double*));
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                (*result).matrix[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(double));
            }
        } else {
            returnValue = NOT_VALID_MATRIX;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    START_TEST(valid) {
      matrix_t matrix;
      matrix_t matrix2;
      matrix_t matrix3;

      create_matrix(2, 2, &matrix);
      create_matrix(3, 0, &matrix2);

      int counter = 1;


      int result = validMatrix(&matrix2);

      ck_assert_int_eq(result, 10);

    }
    END_TEST


    int main() {
      Suite *s1 = suite_create("s21_matrix: ");
      TCase *tc1_1 = tcase_create("s21_matrix: ");
      SRunner *sr = srunner_create(s1);
      int result;
      suite_add_tcase(s1, tc1_1);

      tcase_add_test(tc1_1, valid);

      srunner_run_all(sr, CK_ENV);
      result = srunner_ntests_failed(sr);
      srunner_free(sr);
      return result == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }
```

Comment: Не понятно в чем проблема? `malloc()` если выделил память возвращает указатель, если не выделил (не важно по каким причинам) - возвращает 0 (`nullptr`) - `On success, returns the pointer to the beginning of newly allocated memory. On failure, returns a null pointer.`

Comment: Ну да, вывожу printf("%p ", matrix2.matrix); в мейне, получаю 0x0. Однако, если то же самое запускается в тестах, то там уже, судя по всему, не NULL и оно всегда проходит...

Comment: Инициализируйте структуры, как `matrix_t matrix = {0}` или в `create_matrix` зануляйте поля. У вас в них мусор изначально лежит.

Answer (score 2):

malloc() если выделил память возвращает указатель, если не выделил (не важно по каким причинам) - возвращает 0 (nullptr) - On success, returns the pointer to the beginning of newly allocated memory. On failure, returns a null pointer.
Проблема будет в другом - если память под структуру не выделена, то при вызове `validMatrix(matrix_t *matrix)` будет обращение по нулевому указателю, что является UB. Либо если вы вызовите `validMatrix()` до вызова `create_matrix()` будет сравнение с "мусорными" значениями.

```
int validMatrix(matrix_t *matrix) // если память не выделена, то *matrix == nullptr либо мусорному значению 
{
    if ( (*matrix).columns > 0 && // чтение за пределами своей памяти
         (*matrix).rows > 0)      // чтение за пределами своей памяти
        returnValue = 1;
}

int validMatrix(matrix_t *matrix) 
{
    // если create_matrix() не вызывалась, значит здесь будет не 0
    // если create_matrix() вызывалась, но выделение памяти сбойнуло не на первом выделении, значит здесь будет не 0
    if ((*matrix).matrix != NULL) 
        returnValue = 1;
}
```

Правильность выделения памяти нужно проверять в момент выделения. И до выделения обнулить указатели. А в случае неуспешного выделения - выполнить действия для освобождения ранее выделенной памяти.

```
int create_matrix(int rows, int columns, matrix_t *result) 
{
    // если объекты matrix_t тоже выделяются динамически, то нужно проверить и *result
    if(!result)
       return NOT_VALID_MATRIX;

    // вот тут нужно обнулить все поля matrix_t !!!!!
    // чтобы даже после выхода с негативным результатом поля были обнулены

    if (rows <= 0 or columns <= 0)
       return NOT_VALID_MATRIX;
    
    int returnValue = OK;
    
    // присваивать значения rows и columns лучше после того, как операции выделения памяти завершились успешно - т.е. в конце функции    
//    (*result).rows = rows; 
//    (*result).columns = columns;
    (*result).matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(double*)); // здесь проверить результат выделения

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)      // обнулить все matrix[i]
        (*result).matrix[i] = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        (*result).matrix[i] = malloc(columns * sizeof(double));
        if((*result).matrix[i] == nullptr )  // здесь проверить результат выделения
        {  
            returnValue = NOT_VALID_MATRIX;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // в случае неуспешного выделения - выполнить действия для освобождения ранее выделенной памяти 
    if(returnValue == NOT_VALID_MATRIX)
    {} // освободить ранее выделенную память, обнулить все данные или другие действия и выход с отрицательным результатом
    
    // если всё - ОК
    (*result).rows = rows; 
    (*result).columns = columns;

    return ОК;
}
```

В общем обязательное условие - вызов `create_matrix()` сразу после создания матрицы, до вызовов любых других функций. Для вас `create_matrix()` - аналог конструктора в `C++`.
А в `create_matrix()` необходимо занулять **все** поля `matrix_t`. Это дает гарантии, что:

- если все нули, значит `create_matrix()` отработала с ошибками (память не выделилась или матрицу создать невозможно)
- если указатель не 0 и rows columns положительные - значит память выделена и всё ОК

Comment: У вас тест всё равно завалится. `matrix_t matrix2;` => в полях мусор. `create_matrix(3, 0, &matrix2);` => в полях мусор т.к. выход преждевременный. `int result = validMatrix(&matrix2);` => в полях мусор, а значит результат неизвестен.